# How to remove or lock item in a dropdown list through a button click event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a feature which retrieves executives' expenses from different pages of the website and displays them cumulatively on this page which I am calling invoice. These expenses are shown on invoice page when they select the shopname, shopcity and ShopMonth from respective dropdown lists.

What I am trying to achieve is when they click submit button in the invoice page the ShopMonth gets locked or gets invisible for that shop, so that they cannot make any further changes to that invoice once they have submitted it.

Can anybody tell me what the button click event should be for this kind of functionality?

Here is my code for populating my dropdown lists:

```
protected void selectSchool_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //if logged in user is admin, fills selectSaleMonth with all Sale Months to date

    if (isAdmin == true)
    {
        ShopSelection.SaleMonthAdmin(selectSaleMonths);
    }

    //if loged in user is not admin, fills selectSaleMonths with active SaleMonths for selected shop

    else
    {
        ShopSelection.SaleMonthCoordinator(selectSaleMonth, selectShop.SelectedValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: lock as in lock() around another object until some task has completed or "lock" as in emulate read-only attribute?

Comment: Lock as in read only attribute so that they are not able to edit anything on that page once they submit that.

Comment: Depends on what the design of the program is. You could for example make a class that has a readonly property and then set it on creation of the object. There are a lot of ways to try and do this- what have you tried so far? There is a lot we don't know. What is the "invoice" Where/what is it's datasource? What about the dropdown list?

Comment: Data is comming from different tables stored in database, these tables are populated using other pages of the website where user inputs their expenses, their are two tables which takes data from 4 webpages. These 2 tables naming Goods Expense which takes expneses like electric bills, water bills etc and Expenditures which take expenses like employee salaries etc. There are three dropdown lists one have shopnames, shopcity & third is shopmonth, these are populated by another table called shopinfo, which stores months, shopnames and cities.